# Win Server 2008 Task Scheduler to run PHP file

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, scheduler, task

I am trying to figure out how to open and close IE to run a PHP page on
a daily run.Not sure what to do once I get to the "Start a Program" section
of the task wizard to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke php with your script as an argument:

```
"C:\Program Files\PHP\php.exe" -f "C:\Path\to\your\script.php"
```

The `-f` switch is from the linux version, but I believe it's the same for Windows; you'll also need to specify the correct path to php.exe, wherever that is.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, run your php script locally (as SmallClanger suggests); create a .bat script so you link this .bat into task scheduler.

If you must call the php page remotely, create always a bat script with this line:
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.yourdomain.com/page.php

If you want to close the Internet explorer windows, try with [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=vs.85).aspx) and WScript.Shell object.

Comment: Good point, I was assuming a local script, though the OP does say 'page'. If it's the latter, there are some tools around that can automate refreshes of remote pages, but I'd favour a script with something like wget, which will save you having to load IE each time the task is triggered.

Comment: SmallClanger tell right: wget is the best choise. Download the windows version from http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/.